# Numpy: How can I create a linspace in 3D dimension?

Tags: python, numpy

as a homework task I was given to create an RGB spectrum image just with numpy functions.

This is my current code:

```
zero = np.dstack([
    np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, self.resolution),
    np.linspace(0.0, 0.0, self.resolution),
    np.linspace(1.0, 0.0, self.resolution)
])
spectrum = np.tile(zero, (self.resolution, 1, 1))
```

What this produces is a gradient from red to blue. Now, what is left is to `linspace` the green value into the third dimension.

Anyone here who has some tips how to do that?

Edit: Let me re-phrase - how can I avoid this loop with numpy?

```
spectrum = np.tile(zero, (self.resolution, 1, 1))
for i in range(self.resolution):
    spectrum[i, :, 1] = green[i]
```

Comment: `RGB spectrum image` suggests a 2D, not 3D.

Comment: @QuangHoang The result should be an ndarray with size `(n, n, 3)` - so 3D

Comment: Yes, but then how do you arrange extremes of RGB on the first 2 (image) dimensions (the last being reserved for color).

Comment: @QuangHoang I updated my question

Comment: @9769953 Resolution means width and height, so `resolution = 25` means an image 25 by 25 pixels

Comment: @9769953 It has to be an ndarray with dimensions `(n, n, 3)` because RGB means three values. `(n, n, n)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `for` loop is:

```
spectrum[:, :, 1] = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, resolution)[:, None]
```

**Edit**: after playing with your spectrum, this also do the job:

```
res = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, resolution)
s = np.meshgrid(res, res)
spectrum = np.stack([s[0], s[1], 1-s[0]],axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thank you, you are my hero

Comment: Do you mind giving a short explanation what the indexing at the end means?

Comment: It's called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:~:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.).

Comment: Oh, so you are basically increasing the dimension?

Comment: In a way, yes. Sometimes, you don't need to insert the dimension to broadcast, e.g. `some_array * 10`, where `10` being a `0`-dimension.

Comment: @binaryBigInt see updated answer for different approach.